# Collecting statistics from a large set of files

Tags: octave, vectorization

Is there a faster way to do this

```
function [A,B]=powerplot(basepath,N)
    A=zeros(N,1);
    B=zeros(N,1);
    for k=0:N-1
        filename=sprintf('%s-%d.txt',basepath,k);
        data=load(filename);
        [a,b]=powerfit(data(:,1),data(:,2));
        A(k+1)=a;
        B(k+1)=b;
    end
end
```

where

```
function [a,b]=powerfit(X,Y)
    p=polyfit(log(X),log(Y),1);
    a=exp(p(2));
    b=p(1);
end
```

The files contains measurements on an ensemble, each file captured at different times, containing different number of rows. Can I organize my data in a better way? To speed it up, is it necessary to do this analysis in native code using a library like ROOT?

Comment: Try `profile` to identify the slow lines, maybe `load` is not the optimal choice because it involves some advanced code determining file delimiters, data types etc.

Comment: @Daniel It is load that is slow. So how to load data instead?

Comment: When every iteration take > 3 secs, you could try the parallel package. Furthermore, copy all your files to tmpfs (into ram) when you're using linux. This will reduce i/o latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was `load`. By replacing `load` by `dlmread`, the code became much faster.

```
function [A,B]=powerplot(basepath,N)
    A=zeros(N,1);
    B=zeros(N,1);
    for k=0:N-1
        filename=sprintf('%s-%d.txt',basepath,k);
        data=dlmread(filename);
        [a,b]=powerfit(data(:,1),data(:,2));
        A(k+1)=a;
        B(k+1)=b;
    end
end
```